# CSS end of line character

Tags: css, eol

Okay, what I want is this:
When the <p> tag ends with </p>, I want to add a character at the end of the line. For example

```
<p>Something and more!</p>
```

Should look like

> Something and more!_

Where the '_' (underscore) is the added character. 
Is this possible with CSS?
Is it also possible at the end of a line?

Comment: Why don't you add a padding-bottom: 15px (or whatever your line height is) to the <p> tag's css?

Comment: There is no line (and no spoon).  There are only boxes in HTML and CSS.

Comment: @janoliver: Maybe 1em would be better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible

```
p:after{
    content:"_";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If I've understood your question right, then I think the following works as you require:

```
p:after {
    content: '_';
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xMNuj/).

Which seems compatible even with [IE 8 and above](http://caniuse.com/#search=generated%20content).

Comment: I...don't know. Updated it, though. Thanks for the catch, and the notification.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the pseudo-class `:after`:

```
p:after { content: '_'; }
```

It’s not possible for each line though, as CSS practically does not know about “lines”.